# Android media player stop playing while in background

Tags: java, android, audio

I'm making music player app with simple functionality. But when I listen music on my phone with Android 6, sometimes music stops playing until I turn on display again with power button. Then next song is playing, so it seems like it's problem with loading next song. I tried to write new app just to test it out, for this purpose I used this tutorial:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/background-audio-in-android-with-mediasessioncompat--cms-27030

To this example I added ArrayList with paths to songs. In mediaPlayer onCompletionListener I increase track counter and load new song to media player.

My code:

```
    private void initMediaPlayer() {
         mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
         mMediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
         mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
         mMediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);

         mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
             @Override
             public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer)
             {
                 onTrackCompletion();
             }
    });

    private void onTrackCompletion()
    {
         NextTrack();
         Play();
    }


    private void NextTrack()
    {
        playlistPosition++;
        if (playlistPosition == playlists.get(playlistCurrent).size){
            playlistPosition = 0;
    }

    sendAction(ACTION_TRACK_NEXT);

    if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
        Pause();
    }

        loadSong();
        Play();
    }

    private void loadSong()
    {
        String path = playlists.get(playlistCurrent).getPath(playlistPosition);

        if(path == null || path == "")
        {
            return;
        }

        try 
        {

            try 
            {

                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);

            } catch( IllegalStateException e ) {
                mMediaPlayer.release();
                initMediaPlayer();
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
            }


            initMediaSessionMetadata();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {}

        sendTrackData();
    }
```

I don't know anymore why this doesn't work. In manifest I have WAKE_LOCK permission. I also set wake lock for Media player.

Edit:
Today I tried to move loading song into onPlayFromMediaId. I made broadcast from AutoActivity where is Media player to Main Activity and send back onPlayFromMediaId with path to song. But seems like this doesn't work either.I also find out that changing volume with buttons also wake up app.

Edit2:
I made many tests and added debug string in many places in code. And I found out that app stops at mediaplayer.prepare() until I trigger any action on phone (turn on display, volume up/down, click headset button). But I don't know how to fix this bug. I tried to use prepareAsync, but didn't help.

Comment: You would be better off using a Service to play the music and have your activity talk to the service using intents or broadcasts to control playback.

Comment: In this tutorial is used MediaBrowserServiceCompat. It extends Service class, so its a Service too. But yes. I'm using intent and broadcasts. For now when I trigger onPlayFromMediaId from Main Activity it seems like working. But I need to test is longer than hour to be sure.

Comment: My first guess is that you need to call `startForeground(int, Notification)` when playback starts and then `stopForeground(false)` if the user pauses playback or it finishes playing the songs.

Comment: I made some tests. I added startFreground in service and setPersistent=true in activity, but still sometimes player stops playing. I added some debug string that and found out that is most probably problem with loadSong method. So I tried to change it, but nothing helped. Now I'm using mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(path)); previously I used  mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path); . I don't know if there's any difference in it. I'm out of ideas what can be a cause of it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you use foreground service, the system will kill your process and mediaplayer will stop.
below is a part from from a foreground service ( notification example).

```
builder.setContentTitle(aMessage)                           // required
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentText(this.getString(R.string.app_name))  // required
        .setAutoCancel(false)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setVibrate(new long[]{0L})
        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
int mId = 1489;
startForeground(mId, builder.build());
```

The above code is tested and working fine.