# Android MediaPlayer keeping background music playing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

I use a MediaPlayer and when the MediaPlayer starts it currently stops all background music the phone is playing (ie: Spotify) and I was wondering how to have the spotify music continue playing after the MediaPlayer audio is complete

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus

Comment: when you stopped playing other music to play your `MediaPlayer` you requested an `AudioFocus` with `requestAudioFocus()` to do that, right, now you need to abandon the `AudioFocus` with `abandonAudioFocus()` for more information check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus#kotlin)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android media player stop playing while in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48771947/android-media-player-stop-playing-while-in-background)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do anything on your side. This behaviour is implemented by "Spotify" devs. Although normally, sounds should not be stopped, but decreaced in volume, it is called [audio ducking](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus#automatic-ducking).
Also it is recommended to implement [requesting audio focus](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus) and decide play or not to play your audio depending on the status of the audio focus.